# grouping by date and treatment in R

Tags: r, statistics

I have a time series that looks at how caffeine impacts test scores. On each day, the first test is used to measure a baseline score for the day, and the second score is the effect of a treatment.

```
 Post Caffeine  Score     Time/Date
yes        10   3/17/2014 17:58:28
no          9   3/17/2014 23:55:47
no          7   3/18/2014 18:50:50
no         10   3/18/2014 23:09:03
```

Some days have a caffeine treatment, others not. Here's a question: how do I group variables by the *day* of the week, and create a measure of impact, by subtracting the second days' score from the first.

I'm going to be using these groupings for later graphs and analysis, so I think it's most efficient if there's a way to create objects that look at the improvement in score each day and groups by whether caffeine (treatment) was used.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: so you want pre-post for each day? and what is returned if there is only one value for the day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make a column for the day:

```
df$day = strftime(df$'Time/Date', format="%Y-%m-%d")
```

then I think what you're after is two aggregates:

1) To find if the day had caffeine

```
dayCaf = aggregate(df$Caffeine~df$day, FUN=function(x) ifelse(length(which(grepl("yes",x)))>0,1,0))
```

2) To calculate the difference in scores

```
dayDiff = aggregate(df$Score~df$day, FUN=function(x) x[2]-x[1])
```

Now put the two together

```
out = merge(dayCaf, dayDiff, by='df$day')
```

That gives:

```
      df$day df$caff df$score
1 2014-03-17       1       -1
2 2014-03-18       0        3
```

The whole code is:

```
df$day = strftime(df$'Time/Date', format="%Y-%m-%d")
dayCaf = aggregate(df$Caffeine~df$day, FUN=function(x) ifelse(length(which(grepl("yes",x)))>0,1,0))
dayDiff = aggregate(df$Score~df$day, FUN=function(x) x[2]-x[1])
out = merge(dayCaf, dayDiff, by='df$day')
```

Just replace "df" with the name of your frame and it should work.

Comment: If your format has changed then change the first line of code: 'df$day = strftime(df$'Time/Date', format="%Y:%m:%d")' Is that what you mean?

Comment: This is very helpful. I have two questions. 1. hour of the day is important. in the original data, hour is expressed in H:M:S. disaggregating day into its own variable works for analyzing days, but not hours, because an hour can repeat day to day. Ideally there would be a way to keep day and hours in the same variable. But, if not, i'm open to other ideas

Comment: the second question is, I'm getting an error when i try out the code in the 2nd and 3rd line "Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "dayDiff", value = list(`dat$day` = c("2014-03-17",  : 
  replacement has 2 rows, data has 4". Does that make any sense to you? thanks again!!

Comment: If you change the format of your data (as you seem to have done) you need to change the "format" argument of "strftime". To get hours you want "hourCaf = strptime(df$'Time/Date', "%m/%d/%Y %H")". Then use 'hourCaf' instead of 'dayCaf' in the rest of the code. I recommend reading the help files to understand what is going on - type "?strftime".

Comment: the aggregate command collapses recurring instances of the same day into a single row, and, therefore, it's a mismatch with the dimensions of the dataframe (2 instead of 4). how do i use aggregate to match the existing dimensions of the dataframe?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want to do - I thought you wanted a row for each day with the difference in scores and if there was caffeine. Given your data, there are only two days and so we would expect two rows.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively:

```
DF <- data.frame(Post.Caffeine = c("Yes","No","No","No"),Score=c(10,9,7,10),Time.Date=c("3/17/2014 17:58:28","3/17/2014 23:55:47","3/18/2014 18:50:50", "3/18/2014 23:09:03"))

DF$Time.Date <- as.Date(DF$Time.Date,format="%m/%d/%Y")
DF2 <- setNames(aggregate(Score~Time.Date,DF,diff),c("Date","Diff"))
DF2$PC <- DF2$Date %in% DF$Time.Date[DF$Post.Caffeine=="Yes"]

DF2
```

EDIT: This assumes that your data is in the order that you demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

`data.table` solution. The `order` part sorts your data first (If it is already sorted, you can remove the `order` part, just leave the comma in place). The advantage of this approach is that you are doing the whole process in one line and that it will be fast too

```
library(data.table)
setDT(temp)[order(as.POSIXct(strptime(`Time/Date`, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"))), 
    list(HadCafffeine = if(any(PostCaffeine == "yes")) "yes" else "no", 
         Score = diff(Score), 
         by = as.Date(strptime(`Time/Date`, "%m/%d/%Y"))]

##       as.Date HadCafffeine Score
## 1: 2014-03-17          yes    -1
## 2: 2014-03-18           no     3
```

This solution assumes `temp` as your data set and `PostCaffeine` instead `Post Caffeine` as the variable name (it is bad practice in R to put spaces or `/` into variable names as it limits your possibilities to work with them).